# IndexOutOfBounds ArrayList error

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

So I have two arraylists, one multidimensional and the other just an arraylist. I keep seeming to get an out of bounds error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
>       at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
>       at is15147029.main(is15147029.java:303)

And I have no clue why, what I am doing here is imputing integers from another array into the array list. I've checked that the array is full of integers but whenever I try to add the Integers into the arraylist I get an error.

```
ArrayList<Integer> selOrd = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> ordIndex = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    for(int i = 0; i < finalCost.length; i++) {
        int lowCost = 0;
        if(finalCost[i] > lowCost) {
            lowCost = finalCost[i];
            selOrd.add(0, finalCost[i]);
        }
        else if(finalCost[i] <= lowCost ) selOrd.add(finalCost[i]);
    }
    //Get Average Fitness Cost
    for(int i = 0; i < finalCost.length; i++) total = total + finalCost[i];
    avg = total/(finalCost.length);
    //Sort into s1, s2, s3
    for(int i = 0; i < selOrd.size(); i++) {
        if(selOrd.get(i) > avg) ordIndex.get(0).add(selOrd.get(i));
        if(selOrd.get(i) == avg) ordIndex.get(1).add(selOrd.get(i));
        if(selOrd.get(i) < avg) ordIndex.get(2).add(selOrd.get(i));
    }
```

The error seems to occur when adding the integers to selOrd.

Ant help would be appreciated, I also have a similar problem with another array list in my code. Thank you

Comment: Why are you starting your counter at `1`? `ArrayList` indices start at `0`.

Comment: Sorry I mean to change that, was just testing something

Comment: Are you still getting that exception? The stack trace gives you a line number.

Comment: yeah the line number is :  if(selOrd.get(i) == avg) ordIndex.get(1).add(selOrd.get(i));

Comment: That means, `selOrd` has only one element in it and you are trying to access the index 1 element (the 2nd element which doesn't exist).

Comment: I think is your `if(finalCost[i] > lowCost) {
            lowCost = finalCost[i];
            selOrd.add(0, finalCost[i]);
        }` that cause that because they have only one element

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely the result of hard coded index values.
Specifically `get(1)` and `get(2)`.

You MUST verify that `ordIndex.size() >= 3` in
order to safely execute `get(2)` and
`ordIndex.size() >= 2` to safely execute `get(1)`.

Also,
pay attention to error messages.
The exception clearly states `index 1, size 1`.

If the size of the array is one element, then any attempt to access the second element in the array (which has an index value of 1) must fail.

Comment: I dont really understand what you want to change. I see that you want to verify that it should be a certain length but its an multidimensional arraylist so does it not keep scaling?

Comment: The problem is that you are calling `get(1)` (which accesses the second element in the list) when the list is only one element in length.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance in your code, I don't see you adding anything to the ordIndex ArrayList of ArrayLists, so every get call to that will throw an exception.